# Flash Movie Not Looping After Upload

Tags: flash, actionscript, loops, movie

I imported an FLV file to my FLA flash file, and exported it as an SWF movie.

I want to embed it into my website, and I want it to loop after it ends.

I've already checked the following:

- files are fully uploaded
- using the latest version of flash
- "Publish Preview > Flash" works fine in Adobe Flash CS4
- "Publish Preview > HTML" also works fine in Adobe Flash CS4

Actionscript solutions I've tried:

To the FLV component:

```
on (complete){
this.autoRewind=true;
this.play();
}
```

To the frame where the video was placed:

```
 var myLis:Object = new Object; 
 myLis.complete = function(){ 
 flvPlayer.play(); 
 } 
 flvPlayer.addEventListener("complete", myLis);
```

I've been looking at this for the past week and can't figure it out.
I heard that I might check something called "IDE" but I have no idea what that is or how to check that?  Any help would do wonders.

Thank you!!

Comment: Anyone? :/ I've really been stumped on this one.

Comment: What ActionScript version do you use?

Comment: @amn Actionscript 2.0, and I believe that code I posted is for 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

Turns out I needed a stop() at the beginning of my actionscript for the frame with the FLV component:

```
stop();
var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.complete = function():Void {
    flvPlayer.play();
}
flvPlayer.addEventListener("complete", listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a looping video on your site is not really a good idea. Most video players allow the user to replay the video manually. If you still want to loop the video, read on

Your earlier code is for ActionScript 2 (the old one). Here's the code for AS3:

```
 import fl.video.VideoEvent;
 flvPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, videoFinished);
 function videoFinished(event:VideoEvent){
        flvPlayer.play();
 };
```

You can download Flash Builder from [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/features.html). That's the IDE (Integrated Development Environment) you heard about.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned it earlier, but I'm using AS2.

Comment: No particular reason.  I did try that code with AS3 settings, but it didn't work either.